# how to add artisan command to my package laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

SO i developed a custom package in Laravel 5.4, i add my route,my controllers but i have no idea how to add a artisan command, this is my code :

```
namespace MyPackage;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyPackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';
    }

    /**
    * Register the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
      $this->app->make('MyPackage\Controllers\MyPackageServiceController');
    }
}
```

Normally in the usual case i add a new artisan command and add it to **app/Console/Commands/Kernel.php**, so how can i do that inside my package ?

Comment: did you try calling `Artisan::call('down');` where `down` is your command wherever you need to call an artisan method ?

Comment: Nop i want to created in my own Package not in the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I implemented in my project is added a `Kernel.php` class inside `app/Console/Kernel.php` which extends `ConsoleKernel`, and then added commands and their functionality in separate classes inside  `app/Console/Commands/`, there is a protected variable signature `protected $signature = 'import:zip {path : Zip code file path}';`  which holds the command  I'll post both kernel.php and one command file here .

This is how my kernel.php looks like

```php
<?php
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    {
        /**
         * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $commands = [
            \App\Console\Commands\ProcessZip5UniqueChanges::class,
            \App\Console\Commands\ProcessZip5NonUniqueChanges::class,
            \App\Console\Commands\ImportZipCodes::class
        ];
    
        /**
         * Define the application's command schedule.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
         * @return void
         */
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            // $schedule->command('inspire')
            //          ->hourly();
        }
    
        /**
         * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function commands()
        {
            require base_path('routes/console.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

and here is one of my commands `\App\Console\Commands\ProcessZip5UniqueChanges::class`

```php
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;

    class ImportZipCodes extends Command
    {
        /**
         * The name and signature of the console command.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $signature = 'import:zip {path : Zip code file path}';
    
        /**
         * The console command description.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $description = 'Import zip codes';
    
        /**
         * Create a new command instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
    
        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            $path = $this->argument('path');
            if(file_exists($path)){
                $this->import($path);
            } else {
                $this->error('File not exists');  
            }        
        }
?>
```

Now i can run `php artisan import:zip /path/to/the/uploaded/file`, Hope this helps

**Edit**

Try like this when comes to package, as the commands should be autoloaded

```php
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Package;
    
    class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    
        protected $commands = [
            'Vendor\Package\Commands\MyCommand::Class',
            'Vendor\Package\Commands\FooCommand::Class',
            'Vendor\Package\Commands\BarCommand::Class',
        ];
    
        public function register(){
            $this->commands($this->commands);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Mohammadov , you may get some idea looking into how I'm implemented in my project

Comment: He's trying to ship and register a console command with his package.

Comment: @Mohammadov, as your package is installed inside vendor you service provider name space should be `Vendor/packagename` here is an example, I've added the sample code under Edit.

Answer (score 1):

You bind it like any other class but with the prefix `command.` to the actual command name.

If your command name is `mycommand`, then register is like so.

```
$this->app->singleton('command.mycommand', function () {
    return new MyCommand;
});
```

Found this information based on how laravel registers it's commands.

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/ArtisanServiceProvider.php
```

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5.3 and above, add the following in your PackageServiceProvider's boot method. Make sure to change 'SetupCommand' to yor command class name

```
if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
        $this->commands([
        SetupCommand::class
    ]);
}
```

make sure you have imported your command like

```
use vendor\package\Commands\SetupCommand;
```

Once your package is installed, you will find your command on the php artisan command list